# API Restful java recebe data errada do POST JSON

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest

Tenho uma API Rest em java que está recebendo a data errada.
O JavaScript envia o seguinte JSON:

```
{
"pessdtcad": "2018-02-24",
"dataNascimento": "1984-05-18",
"nome": "GUSTAVO DE FREITAS",
"sexo": "M",
}
```

E o back-end mostra as datas com 1 dia a menos.

Por exemplo, ao adicionar o JSON acima esse é a informação que recebo no back:

```
GUSTAVO DE FREITAS;
Thu May 17 21:00:00 BRT 1984;
Fri Feb 23 21:00:00 BRT 2018
```

Alguém já passou por isso e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: acho que aqui fica umas perguntas sobre qual framework você está utilizando no backend para saber se ele já faz algum tratamento especial com relação as datas recebidas

Answer (score 0):

Seu JSON não tem timezone nem culture definido, então quando chega no seu backend ele assume que está numa timezone padrão e ajusta para sua área.
Sugiro especificar timezone para resolver seu problema.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",timezone = "GMT-3")
```

[Você pode verificar um problema similar sendo resolvido aqui.](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1266)

Comment: Paz, este JSON é enviado através de um POST do HTML, e quando chega no Restful já está com a data errada, mesmo colocando a anotação acima. Teria alguma forma de eu passar esste timezone no HTML?

Answer (score -1):

Eu não tenho reputação suficiente para um comentário, então vou escrever por aqui.

Como você está fazendo esse mapeamento entre o conteúdo enviado na requisição HTTP e o endpoint no JAX-RS? Qual é a classe usada para instanciar os valores de datas?

Se você estiver usando `java.time.LocalDate`, dependendo da sua versão do JAX-RS, a conversão é automática.

Outra possibilidade é utilizar um String para receber o valor da data. Nesse caso, a conversão pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```java
java.time.LocalDate.parse("2023-04-13", java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
```

A classe [*DateTimeFormatter*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) oferece opções para fazer essa conversão para strings de data:

> - sem informação de hora e sem timezone, ex: "2023-04-13"
> - com informação de hora e sem timezone, ex: "2023-04-13T10:15:30"
> - com informação de hora e com timezone, ex: "2023-04-13T10:15:30-03:00"

Sobre a anotação recomendada pelo @Paz, ela é uma anotação específica da biblioteca *Jackson* e não é parte da especificação JAX-RS.

Nesse [post](https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/jaxrs-convert-params), o autor, que participa do desenvolvimento da especificação JAX-RS, mostra uma forma de fazer essa conversão de forma genérica. **Mas, atenção**: dependendo da sua versão, o JAX-RS já faz isso de forma automática.